# Search for specific extension files (shellscript)

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting, I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

path_file_conf=/fullpath/directory/*.conf
if [ -e "$path_file_conf" ];then
    echo "Found file"
else
    echo "No found file"
fi
```

The result is always "No found file" even if I have a .conf files inside /fullpath/directory/ folder.

May I know what part of the code is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
path_file_conf=/fullpath/directory/*.conf
```

May have multiple path names that match. So the value of `$path_file_conf` may end up being, for example:

```
/fullpath/directory/foo1.conf /fullpath/directory/foo2.conf
```

The conditional:

```
if [ -e "$path_file_conf" ]; then
```

Checks for the existence of a single file. If "/fullpath/directory/foo1.conf /fullpath/directory/foo2.conf" doesn't name a "single file", which it won't, then the condition will fail even though the files exist.

You could check this way. If the path doesn't expand, it will fail and exit. If it finds at least one good path, it will succeed and exit.

```
for pf in $path_file_conf ; do
  if [ -e "$pf" ] ; then
    echo "Found"
    break
  else
    echo "Not found"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
for filename in /fullpath/directory/*.conf
do
    if [ -e "$filename" ]  # If finds match...
    then
        echo "Found file"
        echo
    else
        echo "No found file"

    fi
done
```

I haven't tested so I'm not certain it works, but it will at least give you the overall strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The line causing trouble is:

```
path_file_conf=/full/path/directory/*.conf
```

The shell does not do wild-card expansion on the name when there are multiple files to match, or when no files match, so (except in the unusual circumstance of having a file called `*.conf` with an asterisk) the `-e` test fails.  There is probably an option in `bash` to generate an error when a wild card fails to match; I would never use it.

You can use:

```
path_file_conf=( /full/path/directory/*.conf )
```

This gives you an array with the names of the files as the elements of the array.  However, if there are no files that match, it gives you the name as written as the only element of the array.

From there, you can check each file in turn:

```
for conf_file in "${path_file_conf[@]}"
do
    if [ -e "$conf_file" ]
    then echo "Found file $conf_file"
    else echo "No such file as $conf_file"
    fi
done
```

You can determine the number of names with `${#path_file_conf[@]}`, but remember that 1 could indicate a real file or a non-existent file.